# Format error while using join function in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I would need to have joined values from schemasREAD.usage_roles together with string suffix "_R" ultimately creating a role in resource "warehouse_grant_usageREAD_R" called "PROD_FINANCE_DELIVERY_COMMONDATA_READER_R" however getting following error when using "join" function:

```
│   on schemas.tf line 62, in resource "snowflake_warehouse_grant" "warehouse_grant_usageREAD_R":
│   62:   roles         =  "${join("", [ "${each.value.usage_roles}" , "_R"])}" 
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value.usage_roles will be known only after apply
│ 
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "roles": set of string required.
```

Structure looks as following:

```
locals {
  schemasREAD = {
    "COMMONDATA" = {
      database    = "PROD_FINANCE_DELIVERY"
      usage_roles = ["PROD_FINANCE_DELIVERY_COMMONDATA_READER"]
    }
  }
}
```

```
resource "snowflake_warehouse_grant" "warehouse_grant_usageREAD_R" {
  depends_on    = [snowflake_role.role]
  for_each      = local.schemasREAD
  warehouse_name = "PROD_FINANCE_DELIVERY_LOAD_WH"
  privilege     = "USAGE"
  roles         =  "${join("", [ "${each.value.usage_roles}" , "_R"])}" 
  with_grant_option = false
}
```

Comment: What is the goal of that messy join statement? Do you just want to append _R to every entry in usage_roles? And does `schemasREAD` **actually** have those values or is that a simplification?

Comment: Yes, that is my goal and yes, `schemasREAD` does contain this value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [format](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/format) function here instead of `join` as `_R` is not a list.

```
locals {
  schemasREAD = {
    "COMMONDATA" = {
      database    = "PROD_FINANCE_DELIVERY"
      usage_roles = ["PROD_FINANCE_DELIVERY_COMMONDATA_READER"]
    }
  }
}

output "val" {
  value = format("%s%s", local.schemasREAD.COMMONDATA.usage_roles[0], "_R")
}
```

Output of concatenated string::

> [factory@docker-tests terraform-playground]$ terraform apply
>
> Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
>
> Outputs:
>
> val = PROD_FINANCE_DELIVERY_COMMONDATA_READER_R

You might have to iterate through the `usage_roles` to fetch all the roles and append with `_R` but that's easily possible by the above way with [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each)..